# throw the book at my head

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> I had not the vaguest idea what this meant and when I could not
>   remember the words, **my tutor threw the book at my head**, which did not
>   stimulate my intellect in any way.

what does the writer (Russell) mean by "my tutor threw the book at my head"?

Comment: I would read it as literal with no hidden meaning. Because the clause "which did not stimulate my intellect" makes a tongue-in-cheek observation.

Answer (score 0):

It is an idiomatic expression:

***throw the book at someone***

> to punish someone as severely as possible:
>
> - The judge was not lenient – he threw the book at him.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: I'm familiar with the idiom, of course, but "...at my head" is not normally part of it. Are you sure the example in the question wasn't a literal description? I've been in classes where (unfortunately) the teacher did throw things.

Comment: But I confused with the part "...at my head". Why he have not said "threw the book at me" and said "threw the book at my head"? Does it change the meaning? Or it is the same?

Comment: It seems more literal than literary in the context.

Comment: @Kris - could be, in any case it is a form of punishment.